# PHP / Docusign - Verify HMAC signature on completed event

Tags: php, symfony, docusignapi

I'm trying to secure my callback url when completed event is triggered.

**My Controller:**

```
    public function callbackSubscriptionCompleted(
        int $subscriptionId,
        DocusignService $docusignService,
        Request $request
    ) {
        $signature = $request->headers->get("X-DocuSign-Signature-1");
        $payload = file_get_contents('php://input');

        $isValid = $docusignService->isValidHash($signature, $payload);
        if (!$isValid) {
            throw new ApiException(
                Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,
                'invalid_subscription',
                'Signature not OK'
            );
        }

        return new Response("Signature OK", Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

**My DocusignService functions:**

```
    private function createEnvelope(Company $company, Subscription $subscription, LegalRepresentative $legalRepresentative, Correspondent $correspondent, $correspondents) : array
    {
       // ...
       $data = [
            'disableResponsiveDocument' => 'false',
            'emailSubject' => 'Your Subscription',
            'emailBlurb' => 'Subscription pending',
            'status' => 'sent',
            'notification' => [
                'useAccountDefaults' => 'false',
                'reminders' => [
                    'reminderEnabled' => 'true',
                    'reminderDelay' => '1',
                    'reminderFrequency' => '1'
                ],
                'expirations' => [
                    'expireEnabled' => 'True',
                    'expireAfter' => '250',
                    'expireWarn' => '2'
                ]
            ],
            'compositeTemplates' => [
                [
                    'serverTemplates' => [
                        [
                            'sequence' => '1',
                            'templateId' => $this->templateId
                        ]
                    ],
                    'inlineTemplates' => [
                        [
                            'sequence' => '2',
                            'recipients' => [
                                'signers' => [
                                    [
                                        'email' => $legalRepresentative->getEmail(),
                                        'name' => $legalRepresentative->getLastname(),
                                        'recipientId' => '1',
                                        'recipientSignatureProviders' => [
                                            [
                                                'signatureProviderName' => 'universalsignaturepen_opentrust_hash_tsp',
                                                'signatureProviderOptions' => [
                                                    'sms' => substr($legalRepresentative->getCellphone(), 0, 3) == '+33'  ? $legalRepresentative->getCellphone() : '+33' . substr($legalRepresentative->getCellphone(), 1),
                                                ]
                                            ]
                                        ],
                                        'roleName' => 'Client',
                                        'clientUserId' => $legalRepresentative->getId(),
                                        'tabs' => [
                                            'textTabs' => $textTabs,
                                            'radioGroupTabs' => $radioTabs,
                                            'checkboxTabs' => $checkboxTabs
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'eventNotification' => [
                "url" => $this->router->generate("api_post_subscription_completed_callback", [
                    "subscriptionId" => $subscription->getId()
                ], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL),
                "includeCertificateOfCompletion" => "false",
                "includeDocuments" => "true",
                "includeDocumentFields" => "true",
                "includeHMAC" => "true",
                "requireAcknowledgment" => "true",
                "envelopeEvents" => [
                    [
                        "envelopeEventStatusCode" => "completed"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $response = $this->sendRequest(
            'POST',
            $this->getBaseUri() . '/envelopes',
            [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getCacheToken()
            ],
            json_encode($data)
        );
    }

    public function isValidHash(string $signature, string $payload): bool
    {
        $hexHash = hash_hmac('sha256',utf8_encode($payload),utf8_encode($this->hmacKey));
        $base64Hash = base64_encode(hex2bin($hexHash));

        return $signature === $base64Hash;
    }
```

I've created my hmac key in my Docusign Connect and i'm receiving the signature in the header and the payload but the verification always failed.
I've followed the Docusign documentation [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect-hmac)
What's wrong ?

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good to me. Make sure that you are only sending one HMAC signature. That way your hmacKey is the correct one.

As a check, I'd print out the `utf8_encode($payload)` and check that it looks right (it should be the incoming XML, no headers). Also, I don't think it should have a CR/NL in it at the beginning. That's the separator between the HTTP header and body.

### Update

I have verified that the PHP code from the DocuSign web site works correctly.

The payload value must not contain either a leading or trailing newline. It should start with `<?xml` and end with `>`

I suspect that your software is adding a leading or trailing newline.

The secret (from DocuSign) ends with an `=`. It is a Base64 encoded value. Do **not** decode it. Just use it as a string.

### Another update

The payload (the body of the request) contains zero new lines.

If you're printing the payload, you'll need to wrap it in `<pre>` since it includes `<` characters. Or look at the page source.

It contains UTF-8 XML such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0"><EnvelopeStatus><RecipientStatuses><RecipientStatus><Type>Signer</Type><Email>larry@worldwidecorp.us</Email><UserName>Larry Kluger</UserName><RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder><Sent>2020-08-05T03:11:13.057</Sent><Delivered>2020-08-05T03:11:27.657</Delivered><DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" /><Status>Delivered</Status><RecipientIPAddress>5.102.239.40</RecipientIPAddress><CustomFields /><TabStatuses><TabStatus><TabType>Custom</TabType><Status>Active</Status><XPosition>223</XPosition><YPosition>744....
```

We've done some more testing, and the line

```
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

should be **very** early in your script. The problem is that a framework can munge the `php://input` stream so it won't work properly thereafter.

Note [this page from the Symfony site](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/json_request_body.html) -- it indicates that the right way to get the request body is:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;

$app->before(function (Request $request) {
        $payload = $request->getContent();
        hmac_verify($payload, $secret);
});
```

I would try to use the Symfony code instead of `file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: I have only one HMAC signature and `utf8_encode($payload)` display a very long xml content starting with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0"><EnvelopeStatus><RecipientStatuses><RecipientStatus><Type>Signer</Type> [...]`

Comment: I've tried to remove header with `$payload = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', '', $payload);` but it's not working too

Comment: The payload starts with `<?xml ...`

Comment: My xml content now starts with `<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0"> [...] ` but the verification also does not work. My Docusign Connect configuration seems good too, my hmac key is good and I checked the box "Include HMAC Signature".

Comment: I'm still investigating too. I suggest a test: taking the raw body from a service such as webhook.site and copying it into your php program to see if the hmac calculation works or not. That will isolate the calculation from the web input issues

Comment: Is it normal that my xml content is on a single line, without tabulations, new lignes and spaces ? And also when i'm printing the content with `print_r($payload)`, its not displaying tags but only data ? I've tried to remove leading and trailing newlines with `trim` function but still not working.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: The problem was with `utf_encode($payload)`. I've replaced the line to `$hexHash = hash_hmac('sha256',$payload,utf8_encode($this->hmacKey));`

Comment: Good job on solving the problem. Thank you for the follow-up